# Android Studio. XML layout width gets crushed in this relativelayout.

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I align two views side-by-side in RelativeLayout? (Not Linearlayout)

I want to have ViewPager at 50dp width aligned at the right of the screen,
and have pink RelativeLayout take up the rest of the space.

I wish to avoid using 'weight' in Layouts.

Any solution, please?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_platform_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_platform_viewpager"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dashboard_platform_view"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minWidth="50dp">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I've checked it. So, here you go:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="120dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_platform_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/dashboard_platform_viewpager"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/dashboard_platform_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minWidth="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Change your layout as bellow, may help to resolve your issue

```
 <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp">


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_platform_viewpager"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:minWidth="50dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/dashboard_platform_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dashboard_platform_viewpager"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/dashboard_platform_viewpager"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add description what you have change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dashboard_platform_viewpager"` for **RelativeLayout**, and remove `toRightOf` for **ViewPager**

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. same thing happend. Width of 'dashboard_platform_viewpager' turns 0

Comment: no, android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/dashboard_platform_viewpager" for dashboard_platform_view take effect, and remove android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dashboard_platform_view" for dashboard_platform_viewpager